# Firebase Hosting Deployment Error HTTP Error: 500, Couldn't create channel

Tags: firebase-hosting, firebase-cli

I am not able to deploy my website to firebase hosting through `Firebase CLI v9.9.0`.
I don't know what is wrong, please help me.

Thank you!

[image: screenshot of error]

Comment: That doesn't sound like something we can do much about here. Try again in a half hour. If the problem persists, [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*firebaser here*

It looks like there was a bug in a recent update. It's been rolled back now, so you should no longer get this problem if you retry. Thanks for reporting!

Comment: Thanks Man! Now it is Working!